# Passing arguments to a method

Tags: java

```
class method {

public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int numberPerLine) {

    for (int i = ch1; i <= (int) ch2 - (int) ch1; i++) { //starting at ch1, loops until ch2

        if (i % numberPerLine == 0) {      //max 10 characters per line
            System.out.println((char) i);
        }
        else {
            System.out.print((char) i + " ");
        }
     }
   }
}

public class q2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    method.printChars((char) 49, (char) 90, 10); //passes the ASCII values of 1 and Z onto the method

   }
}
```

I'm trying to write a program that takes 3 inputs- (beginning character, ending character and the number of characters per line) and then prints it out. Eg- (49, 90, 10) would print out all the ASCII characters from 1 to Z, 10 per line. I just started learning classes in class, I'm not sure If I'm passing the arguments on to the method correctly.

My program is not printing anything, any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: mmmmm, no, char is a single character, I don't believe you can do it this way, could you explian your question some more?

Comment: I'm trying to write a program that takes 3 inputs- (beginning character, ending character and the number of characters per line) and then prints it out. e.g. (49, 90, 10) would print out all the ASCII characters from 1 to Z, 10 per line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You loop should be  `for (int i = ch1; i <= (int) ch2; i++)` right now `90-49=41` which is obviously `<i(49)` so *it won't print anything*
- `if (i % numberPerLine == 0) {` is incorrect as i starts from `49` and it won't work. You need other counter to `count` the characters and check `if(counter==numberLine){` to change line.

***FOR EXAMPLE***

```
    public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int numberPerLine) {
        int count=1;
        for (int i = ch1; i <= ch2; i++) { 
            if (count == numberPerLine) { 
                System.out.println((char) i);count=0;//reset counter
            }
            else {
                System.out.print((char) i + " ");count++;//increment counter
            }
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake was in the for loop line.  Change it to this:

```
for (int i = ch1; i <= (int) ch2; i++) { //starting at ch1, loops until ch2
```

What you had before was just running for the wrong amount of time as it was going between.

It did have an output when called with a big enough number, but it wasn't the output you wanted in that case (try running `method.printChars((char) 49, (char) 128, 10)` on your old version).

On a side note, you don't need to do the crazy int casting in the loop; it is perfectly legal to do `++` on a char.  So you could simplify the entire `printChars` function to this:

```
public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int numberPerLine) {

    for (char i = ch1; i <= ch2/* - (int) ch1*/; i++) { //starting at ch1, loops until ch2

        if (i % numberPerLine == 0) {      //max 10 characters per line
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't know you could increment characters.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `printf()` and something like

```
public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int numberPerLine) {
    for (char i = ch1; i <= ch2; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%c ", i);
        if ((1 + i - ch1) % numberPerLine == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printChars('1', 'Z', 10); 
}
```

Output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : 
; < = > ? @ A B C D 
E F G H I J K L M N 
O P Q R S T U V W X 
Y Z
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't realize you could pass the characters themselves. I only knew how to pass the ASCII values.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can call the method with `char`s - you don't need to "translate" it to ints:

```
method.printChars('1', 'z', 10);
```

Second, as was suggested by the other answers, the stop condition in the loop is wrong, you shouldn't stop on: `i <= (int) ch2 - (int) ch1` but on `i <= (int) ch2`

And last, it will break the first line before you reach 10 characters unless you change the `if` condition from:

```
if (i % numberPerLine == 0)
```

to:

```
if ((i - ch1 + 1) % numberPerLine == 0)
```

Code:

```
public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int numberPerLine) {
    for (int i = ch1; i <= (int) ch2; i++) { //starting at ch1, loops until ch2
        if ((i - ch1 + 1) % numberPerLine == 0) {      //max 10 characters per line
            System.out.println((char) i);
        }
        else {
            System.out.print((char) i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

and as I mentioned earlier, you can call this method with:

```
method.printChars('1', 'z', 10);
```

And the output will be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 :
; < = > ? @ A B C D
E F G H I J K L M N
O P Q R S T U V W X
Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a b
c d e f g h i j k l
m n o p q r s t u v
w x y z
```